Put breakpoint in dependency package
I have an angular project "anne" depending on "bob", both of them cloned on my local machine.
I want to run "anne" in a debbugger envieronment so that I can put a breakpoint inside bob, preferibly using vscode's chrome or firefox debuggers
If I try to ctrl+click bob's component vscode bring me to the .d.ts file,  without any of the implementation
If I try the plain old chrome's debugger bob's files are all minified in a single .mjs file
I tried with this launch.json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
      {
          "type": "chrome",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Debug Euservices",
          "url": "http://localhost:4212",
          "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "sourceMaps": true,
          "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
              "webpack:///./projects/bob-core/*": "${workspaceFolder}/../bob/projects/bob-core/*"
          },
          "preLaunchTask": "npm: start"
      }
  ]
}

but it still doesn't map correctly bob's package
I've tried in package.json
"bob": "file:../bob/projects/bob-core"

but this break the build
